# What is the best way to split a file having large number of rows into smaller files of fixed rows?

Tags: batch-file

I have several files containing around 50k lines. I need to break them into smaller files of 1k lines each. What is the best way to do this, on a windows platform?.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: With batch-file it can be done, but it is extremely slow. With Powershell it can be done as well, but can also become slow when files are larger

Comment: Probably by installing `split` which is part of **GNU CoreUtils** and can be installed on Windows to make it far more powerful and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Create a powershell file and save it with a `.ps1` extension and add the following powershell code.

```
$Input = "LARGEFILE.txt"
$outName = "smallerfile"
$extension = "txt"
$Max = 10kb
$inputFile = [io.file]::OpenRead($Input)
$buffers = new-object byte[] $Max
$count = $lump = 0
try {
    do {
           $count = $inputFile.Read($buffers, 0, $buffers.Length)
           if ($count -gt 0) {
           $to = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f ($outName, $lump, $extension)
           $toFile = [io.file]::OpenWrite($to)
           try {

               $tofile.Write($buffers, 0, $count)
            } finally {
                $tofile.Close()
            }
        }
        $lump ++
    } while ($count -gt 0)
}
finally {
    $inputFile.Close()
}
```

You need to give the full path and name of the input file, which would be the large file. and then give a unique name of the output files you want, it will store the numbers of each for you. You can also adjust how large you want the output files. So in this instance it will create 10kb files from `LARGEFILE.txt` into `smallerfile.1.txt`, `smallerfile.2.txt`, `smallerfile.3.txt` etc.

*PS!!* you can run the file from `cmd.exe` by running as `powershell .\scriptname.ps1` or by replacing `.\` with the full path to the script. you can also run it directly from powershell.